# Simpler way to work with string numbers?

Tags: java, android, string, parsing, int

Is there a simpler way to do this?

```
int score = Integer.parseInt(tv_score.getText());
score += 100;
tv_score.setText(String.valueOf(score));
```

Comment: You could do `"" + score`

Comment: Keep the score in a class field and don't get it from the TextView.

Comment: java enforces type, u gotta live with it :(

Comment: Actually, the solution is what @MuratK. says.  I was overcomplicating myself, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a simpler way to your primitive objects data type instead of primitive data types

```
Integer score = new Integer(tv_score.getText());
score += 100;
tv_score.setText(score.toString());
```

or you can also do like this to make it more short and precise

```
Integer score = new Integer(tv_score.getText())+100;
tv_score.setText(score.toString());
```

Comment: Don't use `new Integer()`. Make use of the caching capabilities with `Integer.valueOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

int score = Integer.parseInt(tv_score.getText());

This will not work if the number entered, as I can see, in the textfield or textarea is not in decimal format.

```
If the number will always be in decimal format, then use
 - int x = Integer.parseInt("11") + 10;

And for an instance, if the number is in hexadecimal format, then use
- int x = Integer.parseInt("1B", 16) + 10;
```

Hope this will help. :-)